# Is it more performant to use ON or USING or WHERE in a MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

Let's imagine I have a `foo` and `bar` table having both `id` as primary keys.

Is the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
JOIN bar
WHERE foo.id = bar.id
AND foo.id = :id
```

As performant as the following queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
AND foo.id = :id
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
JOIN bar USING (id)
AND foo.id = :id
```

`EXPLAINS` tells me that all those queries are synonyms, but I'm wondering if there are edge cases when using several indexes ? I didn't find any explicit documentation on the subject.

Annex: `EXPLAINS` results.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->     SELECT *
    ->     FROM foo
    ->     JOIN bar
    ->     WHERE foo.id = bar.id
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL        |  100 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bar   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.foo.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->     SELECT *
    ->     FROM foo
    ->     JOIN bar USING (id)
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL        |  100 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bar   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.foo.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->     SELECT *
    ->     FROM foo
    ->     JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL        |  100 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bar   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.foo.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It depends on what you’re doing. They aren’t the same thing, especially ON and WHERE (e.g. outer join). So you’ll use the one that does what you want it to do.

Comment: Most RDBMS will error out if you use an explicit `JOIN` without an `ON` clause, so I would reject your `a JOIN b WHERE a.id = b.id` example for portability reasons alone. Also it's confusing to have the relationship (`ON`) hanging out down in the `WHERE` clause.  As for the `USING` I would make the same Portability argument. It's also dangerously close to `Natural Join` in that the SQL could cause incorrect results after a potentially innocuous `ALTER TABLE` at some point in the future. Otherwise it's all syntactic sugar and primarily opinion based.

Comment: Also you left out, as a potential option, the commonly used syntax  `FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id` Which will also you give you the same results and probably the same EXPLAIN. Ugly and implicit and ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

1) For clause `USING` you have to use fields which exists in both tables and have same names.

But in clause `ON` you can have something like:

```
FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
```

2) In case when you need to use specific index - specify fields accordingly to your index (works for both `using` and `on`).

3) In case you use `mysql` - you can use or `USING` either `ON` both of them works correctly (no one reject any of this clauses).